# Como referenciar o copyright da ferramenta PdfSharp sob a licença MIT?

Tags: c#, licença

Estou precisando fazer um programa em C# que gera um relatório em PDF. Para isso, estou utilizando o [PdfSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/), que está sob a licença MIT. Nesse caso, aonde eu devo colocar a referência à licença do PdfSharp? No relatório gerado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só deve colocar se quiser, a licença MIT não exige isto, você só não pode dizer que foi você que fez, mas pode se calar quanto a isto. Portanto pode colocar onde achar que deve.